# Large object shows up in git pack after deletion

Tags: git, object, git-commit

I'm sure I've deleted this file, but it still shows up in verify-pack. What gives?

> $ git verify-pack -v 
>   .git/objects/pack/pack-5722438014fe04ec9d559810bd7840afb6006858.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -3
>
> bfafbf4c4cd9a5ddbcb637a09c183c6dabe7acde blob   18960384 1061775 
>   9232588 ec890d28afb338b258727f124e0bfbc11f6c0f0d blob   23079936 
>   2279611 1640818 5daf9ca1b4988c240cb9ac9a2d026e5028e9fd8e blob   79966293 3803212 4919563
>
> $ git rev-list --objects --all | grep 5daf9ca1
>   5daf9ca1b4988c240cb9ac9a2d026e5028e9fd8e DriverLib/json_spirit/Debug/json_spirit_reader.obj
>
> $ git log --pretty=oneline --branches --
>   DriverLib/json_spirit/Debut/json_spirit_reader.obj

When I run git log to find out which commit the object is in, there isn't anything that shows up. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a file only records a new commit which does not reference that file; all prior commits on this branch which included the file (and actually any other commit in the repository) might still reference the file's blob object and so the file's contents is not going to leave the repository.

If you need to completely remove a file from the repository (that is, from past revisions as well), you'll need to use [`git filter-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html). Note that this tool actually rewrites commits, and so it's a *sharp* tool — before attempting to rewrite a branch using it, be sure to make another pointer to the original tip of the branch to be rewritten — `git branch` or `git tag` for that.

Another possible cause is that the file is still referenced by some commit accessible via [the reflog](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html).  If so, then either expire the reflog or hand-delete the unwanted entries and run [`git gc --aggressive`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html).

Comment: Sorry I didn't give you the full details. I am getting these results AFTER doing git filter-branch --index-filter. My thought now is that I probably need to do --tree-filter instead?